# GPS in Freefall

Tags: gps

alright,

i tried to capture gps data whilst skydiving yesterday.

the ride up in the plane shows nice steady increments, but the free fall portion goes lumpy, then flat lines until i hit canopy, when all is well with the world again.

free fall doesn't generally exceed 150mph in a belly position so i thought it would be ok, any hints / tips / things to read?

thank you

oh um, galaxy alpha, homebrew code written in android studio.
the timestamps are consistent so it's likely a hardware/gps thing?

edit: looking at the accelerometer data. the phone is getting really buffeted in my pocket... could this mess the reception?

[image: excel chart]

Comment: I don't think this is really an Android question. Even so, do you keep the phone in a chest pocket? If it can't see any satellites in the freefall position, you'd expect lack of data for that portion.

Comment: yeh i wasnt sure to be honest, its not really a programming question either and serverfault isnt really the place either is it? it was in a leg pocket and getting buffeted good, im going to try putting it on my back, hopefully the signal will penetrate the rig.

Comment: @user2983931 Came across a comment that the max theoretical altitude at which a cell phone would still be able to pick up data and communicate with the cell tower depending on the device and the tower was 10000 feet. So yes I'd say it lost connectivity.

Comment: @user145490 thanks mate, but it's all GPS, it accurately showed the lift up to 13500 feet no probs, i'm pretty sure it doesn't need cell connectivity to process GPS data. thanks all the same though.